# Menu overlapping logo on resize

Tags: html, css

Logo on the left, menu on the right.  The menu changes to a mobile menu at 600px and is below the logo, but between 600px and 800px the menu overlaps the logo, and I can't seem to solve it.

I did a bit of research and think it might have something to do with the float property, the menu is set to float right, and there is no float on the logo but when I float the logo or a div wrapped around the logo it breaks the layout.  I feel like it should be an easy solution but I can't seem to figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: One solution is have the menu change at 800px instead of 600px if that's when your menu breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides are fixed width, and the parent that houses both is flexible (based on the window width). When it's smaller, they'll overlap, as you know. There are several solutions.

1: Convert Parent to Fixed Width

This will fix the parent as a specific width, and the logo and menu will never get closer together.

2: Convert the Logo and Menu to Flexible

This will cause the logo and menu to change in width along with the parent, so nothing will ever hit. It won't work with the menu though, because text cannot be set to a % of width (unless you use Javascript).

3: Use Another Media Query

Eventually media queries kick in and change the site to a mobile version. Look at the width at which the menu and logo start to overlap. Set up a media query to change the logo to a smaller width at that point. I'd say 750px is a good break point.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

    .lcla-logo {

        width:300px;

    }

    #menu-splash li {

        margin-left:3px;
        margin-right:3px;

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do something like this -- >

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .lcla-logo{
              width:70%; //you can change this according to you
              margin: 5px auto; //for centering your logo
   }

  //----------------------------------  
  // AND here change your menu to mobile menu
  //---------------------------------

}
```

This may solve your problem

Comment: If you lower the screen width, it already changes to mobile at 600px.

Comment: But its better for you to break it on 800px than 600px because your logo is taking up a litle long width .

Comment: Yes but adding that will break things unless he also changes over to a mobile menu. Better to find the existing changeover and change the number. Or add a second breakpoint.